# Insert Data from Checkbox and Textbox in DB

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox, insert, textbox

I've created two php files with code for an order form for a cafeteria and the correspronding lines of code for inserting the posted values in my database. Here I present them.

CODE FOR addorder_form.php

```
**<?php 

       db_connect();

       $cats=array("Kafedes", "Rofhmata", "Pota", "Snack/Glyka"); 
       $arrlength=count($cats);

    for($i=0;$i<$arrlength;$i++) {  
        $sql = mysql_query('SELECT title FROM products WHERE cname="'.$cats[$i].'"') or die(mysql_error());
        echo '<div id="main_content">';
        echo "<h4 style=color:#800000> ".$cats[$i]."</h4>"; 
        echo "<br />"; 


        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql, MYSQL_BOTH)){
            echo "<div id='center' style='align:center'>";
            echo "<input style='text-align:right;' type='checkbox' action='addorder.php' name='products[]' value='".$row["title"]."'>".$row["title"];
            echo '</div>';

            echo ' <div id="center_side" style="float:right"><form "method="post" action="addorder.php"><input type="text" size="4" padding-left="0.2em" name="quantity"/>';
            echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>';  
        echo '<br />';  
        }
    }
    echo '<form name="addorder" method="" action="addorder.php" onclick="addorder.php">';
                echo '<input type="submit" value="Add order" style="float: right;"><br/>';
                echo '</form>';   
    ?>**
```

CODE FOR addorder.php

```
**<?php
        include_once("buzzcafe_fns.php");
        do_html_header("");




$quantity = '';
$title = '';

if (isset($_POST['quantity']) && isset($_POST['products'])) {
    if(isset($_POST["Submit"])) {
    $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
$title = $_POST['products'];
if($_POST["Submit"] == "Submit")
{   
for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($title); $i++) {
db_connect();
$insertOrder = mysql_query("INSERT INTO orders VALUES('".$title[i]."','".$quantity."')")or die(mysql_error());

    }
echo "Record inserted"; 

}
}
}
?>**
```

When I run them I have non any syntax errors, though it does not work. As far as the db_connect() is set in the buzzcafe_fns.php file I've included and it is checked that works properly. How can I make my "INSERT INTO" work?

Answer (score 1):

```
You can use another insert query
First You will check if $title variable array or not.
Next Using For loop
<?php 
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
$db=mysql_select_db("yourdatabasename here" ,$con);
$count=count($title);
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
mysql_query("INSERT INTO orders SET title='".$title[$i]."', quantity='".$quantity."'");
}
?>
```

Comment: I didn't help a lot .